# How to return the equal points between two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have something like this

```
tes1 = {{1, 2}, {0, 2}, {5, 10}};
tes2 = {{0, 2}, {5, 5}, {1, 2}};
Table[{If[tes1[[i]] == tes2[[j]],
   tes1[[i]], Null ]}, {j, 1, Length[tes1]}, {i, 1, Length[tes1]}]
```

If I use `Print[tes1[[i]]]` instead of tes1[[i]] inside the "If", I got what I need, that is {0,2} and {1,2} only. But I want to convert in a list {{0,2},{1,2}}, how could I do that?

Edit1:
In special, for the lists in https://pastebin.com/r4eCV5vT

If you compare them with Intersection, you will find that some points are not being compared. 
[image: points]
The figure shows two red points, obtained from Intersection and you can see that there is two missed points (actually there is more points that both lists have in common), indicated with arrows.

Edit2:
Doing

```
PtsDown = 
  Table[SetAccuracy[Downn[[i, j]], 3], {i, 1, Length[Downn]}, {j, 1, 
    2}];
PtsUpp = Table[
   SetAccuracy[Upp[[i, j]], 3], {i, 1, Length[Upp]}, {j, 1, 2}];

Table[{If[PtsDown[[i]] == PtsUpp[[j]],
   Print[PtsDown[[i]]],]}, {j, 1, Length[PtsUpp]}, {i, 1, 
  Length[PtsDown]}]
```

Gives

```
{0.*10^-3,8.66}

{0.*10^-3,8.66}

{4.50,2.60}

{4.50,2.60}

{7.50,9.53}

{12.00,3.46}

{12.00,3.46}

{15.00,10.39}

{15.00,10.39}
```

The problem is that I need to copy the points without the repeated ones, after that, we got
[image]

Or using the suggestion

```
 Select[PtsUpp, MemberQ[PtsDown, #] &]
```

Gives

```
{{0.*10^-3, 8.66}, {0.*10^-3, 8.66}, {4.50, 2.60}, {7.50, 
  9.53}, {12.00, 3.46}, {12.00, 3.46}, {15.00, 10.39}}
```

Comment: Intersection?....https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Intersection.html

Comment: I tried but it fails.

Comment: What do you get when you execute `Intersection[Downn, Upp]` in your version/os? I get  4 points: `{{4.5, 2.59808}, {7.5, 9.52628}, {12., 3.4641}, {15., 10.3923}}`  both in v12.0 (Wolfram Cloud) and v9.0 (windows 10).

Comment: Only two points {{7.5, 9.52628}, {15., 10.3923}}. Actually, there are 5 points, as you may notice near from x=0 and y~8 (I guess {-8.88178*10^-16, 8.66025}) one blue point is right under the green one in my picture. So I think we need a function that approximate the numbers, not like "Round" but something with more precision.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intersection[tes1, tes2]
```

> {{0, 2}, {1, 2}}

```
Select[tes1, MemberQ[tes2, #] &]
```

> {{1, 2}, {0, 2}}

**Update:** Using the lists `Downn` and `Upp` from [OP's link](https://pastebin.com/r4eCV5vT):

```
Intersection[Downn, Upp]
```

> {{4.5, 2.59808}, {7.5, 9.52628}, {12., 3.4641}, {15., 10.3923}}

```
ListPlot[{Downn, Upp, Intersection[Downn, Upp]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[.7], AbsolutePointSize[5], Green], 
      Directive[Opacity[.7], AbsolutePointSize[5], Blue], 
      Directive[Opacity[.7], AbsolutePointSize[10], Red]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotLabel -> Row[{"intersection = ", ToString@Intersection[Downn, Upp]}]]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> "12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"

Comment: Neither Intersection nor the other suggestion works in my lists. I made an edit on the post with the lists.

Comment: @Lucas, `Intersection[Downn, Upp]` gives 4 points:
`{{4.5, 2.59808}, {7.5, 9.52628}, {12., 3.4641}, {15., 10.3923}}` (both in v12.0 (Wolfram Cloud) and v9.0 (windows 10)). What are you getting?

Comment: Only two points {{7.5, 9.52628}, {15., 10.3923}}. Actually, there are 5 points, if you look to your picture at x=0 and y=near above 8 (I guess {-8.88178*10^-16, 8.66025}), a green point is missing under the blue one. So I think we need a function that approximate the numbers, not like "Round" but something with more precision.